# How to live reload without restart on additional static resources in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, livereload

I'm attempting to set a new resource location on a spring boot project that is enabled for live reloads but not for application restarts.  I'm able to add additional resources, but any change made in the new directory causes the application to restart.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-additional-paths) on this seems light.  I must be misinterpreting something.

My layout looks like this:

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
      - static
- web
  - dist
```

And my application class looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/dist/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(""file:web/dist/"")
                    .setCachePeriod(0);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.addListeners(new PropertyLogger());

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths", "web/dist/");
        properties.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude", "/dist/**");
        app.setDefaultProperties(properties);

        app.run(args);
    }
```

I've read through several similar questions and this seems to be the best I can do.  Is it possible to enable live reload on dist without a full application restart?

By the way, my IDE is IntelliJ.  I'm beginning to wonder if IntelliJ needs to exclude the dist directory.  I'll followup if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I've beaten this to death and have finally found a working solution.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths", "web/");
    properties.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude", "dist/**");
    app.setDefaultProperties(properties);
```

Defining the web directory as an additional path combined with the pattern used for additional exclude does the trick.

I won't mark this as accepted unless there are upvotes to back my conclusion.